# Create sector zones in plotly

Tags: python, colors, plotly, chart-director

In ChartDirector you can set different zones of the chart as different colours depending on the data values:

```
c.angularAxis().addZone(4.5, 5.5, 0xffff00)
c.angularAxis().addZone(7.5, 8.5, 0xffff00)
```

[image]

However I cannot find any equivalent for plotly. I have been searching through the chart attributes (https://plot.ly/python/reference/) and nothing appears to do the equivalent. Is this possible within Plotly?

Comment: Can't answer this as I haven't tried it myself, but I would think that modifying a [wind rose chart](https://plot.ly/python/wind-rose-charts/) would work.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look into [Gauge Charters](https://plot.ly/python/gauge-charts/), and see if they might work for you. Some hacking/modifications may be necessary however.